# Exporting "Artist-mode" drawing to PDF through Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Do you know how to export an Artist-mode drawing using the Org-mode export feature?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know that, but whenever I need to do some vector graphics in Org, and then export that to PDF, I use Tikz LaTeX package. Of course this is different from ASCII art, but maybe that's what you actually wanted? PS. If I had to export `artist-mode` drawing, I'd just make it a verbatim latex environment.

Comment: Org mode supports [ditta export](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-ditaa.html), which is a particular case of ascii art.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "[example blocks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html)" to do this... Example blocks are small pieces of document that are outputted literally in monospaced text, regardless of export mode.

You can create these easily by typing "`<e`" in an Org mode buffer and then hitting `[Tab]` like this:

[image]

If you put your cursor in the block and hit `C-c '`, you can get into a dedicated buffer to edit the contents of the block. In here you can `M-x artist-mode` and draw something. I'm not much of an artist, but you should see a buffer like so:
[image]

Hit `C-c '` again when you are done and your buffer should now have your art in it:
[image]

Add some header arguments to set up your LaTeX export:
[image]

`C-c C-e` to export like you usually would.
[image]

And voila! You have a PDF you can donate to your local art museum to capture the hearts of your many dedicated fans and bring tears to critics' faces!
[image]